# How to manipulate the groupheader section in XamDataGrid

Tags: wpf, infragistics

[image]

The Total Transaction = 10,000 is the summary part that I want to display. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FieldLayout.FieldSettings.SummaryDisplayArea = SummaryDisplayAreas.InGroupByRecords;
```